# Continuous function between topological space and metric space imply metrizality of topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Im trying to prove that if the conclusion of Urysohn's lemma holds then X is normal. I  was thinking that if X is metrizable then X i T4 then X is normal. But dont feel 100 percent confident with my assumption that if there exist an continuos function between  the topological space X and metric space then X is metrizable.

Comment: There are non-metrizable compact (Hausdorff) spaces. They are normal, so Urysohn's lemma holds there.

Comment: ty, I guess the inverse of f has to be cts aswell for my assuption to hold @DanielFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ satisfies Urysohn's lemma:

for every $A$ and $B$, disjoint, non-empty closed subsets of $X$, there exists a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A$, and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in B$.

To see that $X$ is normal, start with two disjoint closed non-empty subsets $A$, and get $f$ as above. Now define $U = f^{-1}[(-\infty, \frac{1}{2})]$ and $V = f^{-1}[(\frac{1}{2}, +\infty)]$, which are open as inverse images of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ under a continuous function.

Clearly $U$ and $V$ are disjoint (no point of $X$ can map both into $(-\infty, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, +\infty)$ under $f$) and all points of $A$ map to $0$, so are in $U$, and also $B \subset V$. So $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $A$ and $B$ respectively.